# Test mocked service then/catch on function - Angular/Karma

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

I have a coverage issue with my Angular/Karma tests.

I created a component that has a signUp() function

*angularFireAuthSignOutSpyObj* is a spy of *this.auth* from the component (Firebase Auth)

```
  signUp() {
    if (this.registrationForm.valid) {
      this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword
      (
        this.registrationForm.get('email')?.value,
        this.registrationForm.get('password')?.value
      )
        .then(() => {
          this.appMessage = "Account created !";
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.appMessage = error.message;
        });
    } else {
      this.appMessage = 'Submit logic bypassed, form invalid !'
    }
  }
```

I'm testing this component function with a karma test as is

```
  it('should submit registration with form values', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'signUp').and.callThrough();
    angularFireAuthSignOutSpyObj.createUserWithEmailAndPassword.and.returnValue({
      then: function () {
        return {
          catch: function () {
          }
        };
      }
    });
    component.registrationForm.controls.email.setValue('test@email.com');
    component.registrationForm.controls.password.setValue('ValidPass123');
    component.registrationForm.controls.passwordCheck.setValue('ValidPass123');
    expect(component.registrationForm.valid).toBeTruthy();
    debugElement.query(By.css("button")).triggerEventHandler("click", null);
    expect(component.signUp).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword)
      .toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        component.registrationForm.controls.email.value,
        component.registrationForm.controls.password.value)
    // expect(component.appMessage).toEqual('Account created !');
  });
```

As you can notice the last *expect* is commented out as it returns an *Error: Expected undefined to equal 'Account created !'.*
This is because even though *this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword* is defined in the mocked service *angularFireAuthSignOutSpyObj*, and is correctly called with the 2 expected arguments, I have no control over the *then* and *catch* functions that are defined.

They are defined so it won't trigger an error when trying to access it in the *signUp()* function. But **what I would like to do** is trigger the then(() => ...) and the catch(() => ...) so I can test/check that the app.message was correctly updated.

All the exceptions work until the last one. I feel like that I need to modify something in my *createUserWithEmailAndPassword.and.returnValue* to probably return something that triggers the then or the catch.

```
    angularFireAuthSignOutSpyObj.createUserWithEmailAndPassword.and.returnValue({
      then: function () {
        return {
          catch: function () {
          }
        };
      }
    });
```

Anyone has an idea on how I could test the actual auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword result behaviour of my component ?

Thanks very much !

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey just wanted to post an update as I managed to do exactly what I needed. Thanks to @JeffryHouser for the heads up.

So basically my component initially expects a *Promise* from the query. If the results come back normal (UserCredentials) we simply update the appMessage string with a successful message. If not (catch) we return the error **message**.

Those are the changes I made on the test side in order to simulate the resolve (normal result of the promise, and below how to trigger the catch)

- Set the test as async with **fakeAsync()**
- Spy on every function that are used from the user click()
- Specified a return as Promise for the *angularFireAuthSignOutSpyObj.createUserWithEmailAndPassword* function
- Simulate the async flow with *tick()*
- Detect the changes following the end of promise flow with *fixture.detectChanges()*

The appMessage item is correctly updated following the process

**Here is the code**!

**Spy declaration**

```
let angularFireAuthSignOutSpyObj: jasmine.SpyObj<any>;
...
 beforeEach(async () => {
    angularFireAuthSignOutSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('AngularFireAuth',
      ['createUserWithEmailAndPassword']);
    ...
      });
```

**User credentials item**

```
//Only setting the fields needed
export const testUserCredentials: UserCredential = {
  user: {
    providerData: [
      {
        email: 'test@email.com',
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Test**

```
  it('should submit registration with form values', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'signUp').and.callThrough();
    angularFireAuthSignOutSpyObj.createUserWithEmailAndPassword.and.callFake(() => new Promise(
      resolve => {
        resolve(testUserCredentials);
      })
    );

    component.registrationForm.controls.email.setValue('test@email.com');
    component.registrationForm.controls.password.setValue('ValidPass123');
    component.registrationForm.controls.passwordCheck.setValue('ValidPass123');
    expect(component.registrationForm.valid).toBeTruthy();
    debugElement.query(By.css("button")).triggerEventHandler("click", null);
    expect(component.signUp).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword)
      .toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        component.registrationForm.controls.email.value,
        component.registrationForm.controls.password.value)
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.appMessage).toEqual('Account created : test@email.com');
  }));
```

**How to trigger the error instead of the resolve**

```
    angularFireAuthSignOutSpyObj.createUserWithEmailAndPassword.and.callFake(() => new Promise(() => {
      throw {message: 'test purpose failure'};
    }));
```

**Updated register.component.ts**

```
  signUp() {
    if (this.registrationForm.valid) {
      let createdEmail: string | null | undefined;
      this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword
      (
        this.registrationForm.get('email')?.value,
        this.registrationForm.get('password')?.value
      )
        .then((userCredential: UserCredential) => {
          userCredential?.user?.providerData?.forEach(userInfo => {
            createdEmail = userInfo?.email;
          })
          this.appMessage = "Account created : " + createdEmail;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.appMessage = "Account creation failed : " + error.message;
        });
    } else {
      this.appMessage = 'Submit logic bypassed, form invalid !'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the code where you created the spy.  Also a bit weird you're using promises instead of Observables. But, I'd look into spying on the method--not the class, and returning a promise that you control:

```
const resolveFunction;
const rejectFunction;    
beforeEach(() => {
 spyOn(component.auth, 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword').and.returnValue(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   resolveFunction = resolve;
   rejectFunction = reject;
 })
}
```

Now from your tests you can control when the promise is rejected or resolved just by calling those functions:

```
it('test catch block', () => {
   // some code
   rejectFunction('some error object');
})
it('test then block', () => {
   // some code
   resolveFunction('some error object');
})
```

[More info about creating promises manually](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that !

Here is my code to create the spy
```
    angularFireAuthSignOutSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('AngularFireAuth',
      ['createUserWithEmailAndPassword']);
```

I'm actually looking for the best way/practices to test this component. I'm willing to change the technique. What should I look for regarding Observables ?

Comment: I tried this code
`
    let resolveFunction: Function;
    let rejectFunction: Function;
    angularFireAuthSignOutSpyObj.createUserWithEmailAndPassword.and.returnValue(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolveFunction = resolve;
      rejectFunction = reject;
    }));
...
    resolveFunction('success');
`
Unfortunately, I'm getting the same result. Note that I get this error
_Variable 'resolveFunction' is used before being assigned._

Comment: That could happen if the promise is never listened to, or if the spy is set up incorrectly.  I don't understand what this is `angularFireAuthSignOutSpyObj` is, but your syntax looks wrong for spying; you have to 'and.returnValue()' on the spy; not an object within the spy.